# How to determine the closed form of this Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, closed-form-expressions, elliptic-functions

Consider the Series
$$
S(z) \equiv \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \ne 0} \frac{ 1 }{ \sin n\pi \tau \sin 2n \pi \tau } e^{2\pi i n z} \ , \quad \operatorname{Im}\tau > 0
$$
I am trying to find its **closed form**. My current idea is by exploiting the following total difference equaiton
$$
S(z + \tau) - S(z - \tau) = 2i \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \ne 0} \frac{ 1 }{ \sin n\pi \tau } e^{2\pi i n z} \ ,
$$
where the sum on the right can be identified in terms of Jacobi-theta function as
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \ne 0} \frac{ 1 }{ \sin n \pi \tau }e^{2\pi i n z} = \frac{ 1 }{ \pi } \frac{ \vartheta'_4(z|\tau) }{ \vartheta_4(z|\tau) } \ .
$$

It is easy to find that (for any $\lambda$)
$$
S_0(z) = - \frac{ 1 }{ 8\pi^2 } \frac{ 2 }{ 1 + \lambda } \bigg(\frac{ \vartheta'_4(z|\tau)^2}{ \vartheta_4(z|\tau)^2 } + \lambda \frac{ \vartheta''_4(z|\tau) }{ \vartheta_4(z |\tau) } \bigg)
$$
satisfies the above difference equation. But apparently, there could be an ambiguity of an **elliptic function** with $2\tau$ as one periodicity.

**I wonder if there is a way to fix the ambiguity? Or other method to determine its closed form?**

Comment: doesn't the sum diverge?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker the parameter $τ$ is complex with a positive imaginary part. To me, the coefficient seems to go down exponentially and the series converges.